# How to addClass on top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add addClass on the top of page without having to scroll. In other words, when you first land on the page the animation should start with the addClass.

My code works once you start scrolling down the page; even when you tap the scrollbar once the addClass kicks in.

But when the you're at the top of the page and you don't scroll down, nothing.

HTML:

```
<div class="row"> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {  0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(20px); }  100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0); }  } 
@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {  0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px); }  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }  } 
@-o-keyframes fadeInUp {  0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px); }  100% { opacity: 1; -o-transform: translateY(0); }  } 
@keyframes fadeInUp {  0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(20px);  }  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0);  }  } 


.row.animate {  
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;  
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp; 
    -ms-animation-name: fadeInUp; 
    -o-animation-name: fadeInUp; 
    animation-name: fadeInUp; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
    -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s; 
    animation-duration: 0.5s;  
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    -o-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both;  
    animation-delay: 0.03s;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
(function($) {

  $.fn.visible = function (partial) {

      var $t            = $(this),
          $w            = $(window),
          offset        = 0,
          viewTop       = $w.scrollTop(),
          viewBottom    = viewTop + $w.height(),
          _top          = $t.offset().top,
          _bottom       = _top + $t.height(),
          compareTop    = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
          compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);  


// Already visible modules
$(".row").each(function(i, el) {
  var el = $(el);
  el.css("opacity","0");
  if (el.visible(true)) {
    setTimeout(function(){el.addClass("animate","50");},50 + ( i * 50 )); 
  } 
});

$(window).scroll(function(event) {

$(".row").each(function(i, el){
    var el = $(el);
    el.css("opacity","0");
    if (el.visible(true)){
        setTimeout(function(){el.addClass("animate","50");},50 + ( i * 50 ));
    }



});


});
```

Comment: `$(window).scroll(function(event) {` --> is the stuff in here the stuff that's happening after you start scrolling?

Comment: it is very, very possible your return statement from your `visible` plug in is returning `false` for every `".row"` instead of `true` for the visible row(s). Check the return value to verify.

Comment: @Katie.Sun Yes that is correct

Comment: Does it work the way you want it to when you take it out of there?

Comment: It's working as expected, or I'm missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/azeos/xhdrgskv/

Comment: @Katie.Sun No it does not. I need the code to add addClass to each (.row) that is visible on page refresh or landing on the page for the first time. addClass is only working when I scroll

Comment: @azeós Oh man! It's working in jsfiddle but not working on my end. Should I be using the latest jQuery file?

Comment: @AndruwCruz jQuery version doesn't appears to be the problem, tried with 1.9.1 and it works. You should put the `opacity: 0` in your CSS instead of the JS as has been suggested.

Answer (score 1):

So that means you need to initialize the code that is inside the scroll handler. So you can either break it out into a function and call it

```
function scrolled (event) {
  ...
}
$(window).scroll(scrolled);
scrolled();
```

Or you can trigger the scroll event so the code inside will run.

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) { 
  ...
}).trigger("scroll");
```

Doing this you do not need to duplicate any code.

Below, code fades in when loaded and scrolled.

```js
(function($) {

  $.fn.visible = function(partial) {

    var $t = $(this),
      $w = $(window),
      offset = 0,
      viewTop = $w.scrollTop(),
      viewBottom = viewTop + $w.height(),
      _top = $t.offset().top,
      _bottom = _top + $t.height(),
      compareTop = partial === true ? _bottom : _top,
      compareBottom = partial === true ? _top : _bottom;

    return ((compareBottom <= viewBottom) && (compareTop >= viewTop));

  };

})(jQuery);


$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  $(".row").each(function(i, el) {
    var el = $(el);
    el.css("opacity", "0");
    console.log(el[0], el.visible(true))
    if (el.visible(true)) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        el.addClass("animate", "50");
      }, 50 + (i * 50));
    }
  })
}).trigger("scroll");
```

```css
div {
  width: 50%;  /* so it scrolls on the page */
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

.row.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -ms-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -o-animation-name: fadeInUp;
  animation-name: fadeInUp;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-delay: 0.03s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</div>
```

I would update the CSS to have opacity to be zero by default and not set it with the JavaScript code. And I would make sure that you are running this with document.ready to make sure the content has fully loaded.

Comment: Don't think that's the issue. The OP doesn't want to scroll - it only works when page is scrolled. the problem is with the return from the `visible` plugin.

Comment: Look at the code block above that: `el.visible(true)` here the "visible" part is the jQuery plug in at the top of the page. The OP expects every "visible" row to get the "animate" class through THAT code. Not the scroll code.

Comment: @RandyCasburn he says: *My code works once you start scrolling down the page; even when you tap the scrollbar once the addClass kicks in.*

Comment: @RandyCasburn I just made the OPs code run with my suggestion. It appears to work. Maybe I am also wrong. Seems like the original code should have also worked, but it did duplicate code. I am testing chrome osx.

Comment: Haven’t tried your code yet but my code seems to run fine of jsfiddle but not on my server @epascarello

Comment: okay so time to figure out what is different. So what is different with the static code and on the server? Is something being loaded dynamically? Since we have no clue what you are doing it is just a guessing game.

Comment: @epascarello the only thing that is different is that the js code in a separate file. I will fix the opacity css and put the JavaScript code inside the html file and see if that works on my end

Comment: Where is the JavaScript at in your document? Head or end of Body? My guess it is in the head and you are checking before page loads. Fiddle defaults to window.onload and snipplet runs at the end of the body. So use document ready around your code.

Comment: @epascarello that's exactly what the problem was, js should have been at the end of the body. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello that's exactly what the problem was, js should have been at the end of the body. Thank you!!